# Problems plotting price data against my datetime which is indexed

Tags: pandas, csv, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df=df.set_index('datetime')
data = df.filter(['avgLowPrice'])
plt.plot(data['avgLowPrice'])
plt.show()
```

the graph looks like this:[image]
I have no idea why its doing this...

Comment: It's supposed to look like a normal time graph with price as my y value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your DataFrame is not sorted by the index, i.e.
consecutive rows have "intermixed" (instead of ordered) index values.

Sort your DataFrame, even in-place:

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

and then generate your plot.

Another (not related) hint, to make your code more concise:

To read your input file, convert *datetime* column to *datetime* and
set it as the index, in one go, run:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['datetime'], index_col='datetime')
```

Comment: Ok so this helped a lot thankyou, but it is only showing 10 days but my data is every 6 hours for like 2 months, could you help?

Comment: I suppose that your plot contains all points drawn, but *x* labels are printed for only selected values, e.g. every few days.
To check it, create an auxiliary DataFrame, for a shorter period  (e.g. a few days) and generate just the same printout from it.
Get also all unique values from the index of your source DataFrame, count them and check whether you have "full coverage" of the period od interest.

Comment: The issue was that sort index was sorting the datetime as day month year and my data was year month day, its sorted now ty